# How to redirect to other view in OpenERP7?

Tags: xml, redirect, odoo, openerp-7

I created a function (in `res.partner model`) which does some things and after that redirects to other view of other different model (`event.event`). Here is the code:

```
wiz_data = self.read(cr, uid, ids)[-1]
datas = {
    'event_id': wiz_data.get('event') and wiz_data['event'][0] or None,
    'event_name': wiz_data.get('event') and wiz_data['event'][1] or None,
}

data_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
tree_data_id = data_obj._get_id(cr, uid, 'event', 'view_event_tree')
form_data_id = data_obj._get_id(cr, uid, 'event', 'view_event_form')
tree_view_id = False
form_view_id = False
if tree_data_id:
    tree_view_id = data_obj.browse(cr, uid, tree_data_id, context=context).res_id
if form_data_id:
    form_view_id = data_obj.browse(cr, uid, form_data_id, context=context).res_id

return {
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'view_id': [datas['event_id'] or False],
    'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'), (form_view_id, 'form'),],
    'res_model': 'event.event',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'nodestroy': True,
    'target': 'current',
    'flags': {'tree': {'action_buttons': True},
              'form': {'action_buttons': True},} 
}
```

With that return, the form and tree I want are opened, but the menu which appears on the left (out of the view) belongs to the old model (`res.partner`), and on the top menu the option **Clients** is selected. I would like to redirect to the view of an event, with its own left menu and seeing the option **Events** selected on the top menu.

How can I redirect to the whole page of events?

Comment: might be this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180529/tree-view-to-be-called-through-button-in-openerp-7/25181627#25181627

Comment: Thank you @Odedra, but this is not the same case. I am getting perfectly the tree and form view I want. The problem is the enviroment options around it. For example: Clients have a left menu with a lot of options, and Events have only three (Events, Registrations and Type of events). When I get the views of Event, the left menu is the Clients one (with a lot of options) instead of the Events one (the menu with the three options).

Comment: ohh, than i think might be issue of security rights.

Comment: @Odedra thank you, I will take a look to that point, and then I will comment you.

Comment: I wasn't able to achieve this, in spite of having every security rights opened for this user and these views.